# Help Interpreting KCross and Pairwise Correlation Function Tests for Spatial Point Patterns (R)

Tags: r, spatial

I have a dataset consisting of two spatial point patterns. I would like to see if there is any correlation at all between the general patterns.

I have tried the K Cross and Pairwise Correlation Function in R (with spatstat)- but to be honest I have little clue as to how to interpret these. Googling this subject does not yield any answers in this case!

Can anyone advise me into how I would intepret these graphs? And, is this actually the best approach? I would ideally like a number of significance showing how the datasets correlate.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I recommend you first read up on the tools you're using, starting with Ripley's K. For that first set of plots you have a blue line, which is the theoretical homogeneous poisson point process. Deviation away from that means there's evidence against the null hypothesis of random noise. PCF is similar to ACF (I believe), so review http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~bartlett/courses/153-fall2010/lectures/3.pdf

Comment: Your (cross) pair correlation function (pcf) plot looks weird. I think you should check the code for that. It has nothing to do with ACF (I believe). The interpretation of K cross is a bit more involved than what @Jon writes. The theoretical blue line is consistent with uncorrelated patterns, but not necessarily Poisson.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a (very biased) opinion on where you should read up on these tools: Chapter 14 of [Spatial Point Patterns: Methodology and Applications with R](http://spatstat.github.io/book/) by Baddeley et al. (incl. me).

This is the companion book to the spatstat package, and it really should help you a lot to understand what you are doing.

Also you need to ask yourself what you exactly mean by correlation in this case. Is it: "If I'm at a typical point of the FD process then I expect to see more points of the GPS process close by than by pure chance."?

Finally, your datasets look like they definitely don't have a uniform distribution over space, so you need to take that into account (e.g. `Kcross.inhom`).

Chapter 7 of the book is available for free download and gives you the general idea about what the K-function and pair correlation function are when you have points of only one type, but to understand the multitype/multivariate setup you really need chapter 14.

Comment: Thanks Ege - I have checked out your book already but haven't gotten the funds yet for purchase. I didn't consider using the inhom kcross so I will give that a go.

Comment: Indeed, for correlation, I was curious if there were more GPS points near an FD than points that were randomly distributed. I hope I can find a simple answer in your book... ideally I would like a p-value or an equivalent- but I don't think that is generated with these types of statistics.